# Fabric.js clip text to rectangle

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js to render objects on canvas. When I add text and change it's width, text is beyond selection area. How to clip text to rectangle that represents width and height properties?

EDIT: This is the solution that I found to be working:

```
var text = 'Some text';        
var textSample = new fabric.Text(text, textDefaults);

textSample.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    ctx.rect(-textSample.width / 2, -textSample.height / 2, textSample.width, textSample.height );
}

canvas.add(textSample);
```

Where textDefaults is a text properties.

Comment: I didn't understand the last sentence, which is unfortunate, cause that contains the actual question. Usually making like a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the related code goes a long way in here.

Comment: By 'rectangle that represents width and height properties' i meant selection area. I will try to solve this problem and provide appropriate jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45zng4ge/)

I belive this is what you want. Maybe you forgot `canvas.renderAll();`